# Arch Linux won't play sound at all

Tags: arch-linux, audio, hdmi

My Arch Linux installation refuses to play sound regardless of what I do. I have run `aplay -l` and it is recognizing my sound cards.
Here is the output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here is the output of `lspci -k`:

```
Usage: lspci [<switches>]

Basic display modes:
-mm             Produce machine-readable output (single -m for an obsolete format)
-t              Show bus tree

Display options:
-v              Be verbose (-vv or -vvv for higher verbosity)
-k              Show kernel drivers handling each device
-x              Show hex-dump of the standard part of the config space
-xxx            Show hex-dump of the whole config space (dangerous; root only)
-xxxx           Show hex-dump of the 4096-byte extended config space (root only)
-b              Bus-centric view (addresses and IRQ's as seen by the bus)
-D              Always show domain numbers
-P              Display bridge path in addition to bus and device number
-PP             Display bus path in addition to bus and device number

Resolving of device ID's to names:
-n              Show numeric ID's
-nn             Show both textual and numeric ID's (names & numbers)
-q              Query the PCI ID database for unknown ID's via DNS
-qq             As above, but re-query locally cached entries
-Q              Query the PCI ID database for all ID's via DNS

Selection of devices:
-s [[[[<domain>]:]<bus>]:][<slot>][.[<func>]]   Show only devices in selected slots
-d [<vendor>]:[<device>][:<class>]              Show only devices with specified ID's

Other options:
-i <file>       Use specified ID database instead of /usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids
-p <file>       Look up kernel modules in a given file instead of default modules.pcimap
-M              Enable `bus mapping' mode (dangerous; root only)

PCI access options:
-A <method>     Use the specified PCI access method (see `-A help' for a list)
-O <par>=<val>  Set PCI access parameter (see `-O help' for a list)
-G              Enable PCI access debugging
-H <mode>       Use direct hardware access (<mode> = 1 or 2)
-F <file>       Read PCI configuration dump from a given file
```

Here is the output of `sudo alsactl init`

```
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "ATI R6xx HDMI" "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700" "0x103c" "0x8a31"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Found hardware: "acp" "" "" "" ""
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Here is the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i audio`

```
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8a31
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 87, IOMMU group 14
Memory at d05c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8a31
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 85, IOMMU group 18
Memory at d0580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_sof_amd_renoir

04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8a31
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 88, IOMMU group 19
Memory at d05c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Oddly the sound cards seem to be HDMI so maybe that is the issue?

This is an HP Envy x360 and it has worked perfectly other than this small problem. I would like to be able to play sound though and would greatly appreciate any help in solving this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried poking around in `alsamixer` to see if your channels are muted? If they are, they will display "MM" under the volume bar, and you can unmute them with the `m` key. If unmuted, they should display "00". Also, are you using PulseAudio?

Comment: HD-Audio Generic ? Hmmm… I suspect some fallback in there. Missing some codec ? Could you be more verbose about your audio controller (lspci -k) and post as part of your question the output of cat yourkernel.config.file|grep CONFIG_SND_HDA ?

Comment: And of course try to aplay on card 1 (default likely to be 0)

Comment: my channels were muted in alsamixer but it still isn't working even when i unmuted them, about to try a reboot to see if that helps.@Qba

Comment: edit: reboot didn't help moving on to next steps

Comment: unfortunately i'm not sure what mykernel is for mykernel.config.file and i'm not sure how to find out

Comment: @MC68020 i'm not familiar with aplay and  ```aplay on card 1``` or ```aplay card 1``` don't seem to do anything

Comment: My sound issues in Arch are usually resolved by installing `pulseaudio-alsa`. Maybe that'll be helpful to you, if you don't already have it installed.

Comment: sorry no joy @345422 i installed pulseaudio-alsa and rebooted and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I had no sound after copying my existing Arch onto new hardware, and then found https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1965434#p1965434. Running `sudo pacman -S sof-firmware` fixed it for me. Does that help in your case?

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo alsactl init` as well as report on whether or not that fixed anything? Maybe udev is not correctly identifying the hardware and not loading correct drivers.

Comment: sof-firware didn't work, i'm pretty sure i had installed it a while ago @terdon

Comment: i added ```sudo alsactl init``` output for you @Qba

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [thread on the ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970699&p=12337464#post12337464) in which the OP describes the same problem and also has the same `ATI R6XX HDMI` device. The solution for this was setting the kernel flag for `radeon.audio=1` by doing the following:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor
2. Find the entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
3. Add `radeon.audio=1` at the of the double quoted part
4. Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`

For Example:

Change the original `/etc/default/grub` entry:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet radeon.audio=1"
```

Do not edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as is instructed in that thread by one user.

If this does not work, or `radeon.audio=1` is already set, could you please report which devices are listed when you go into `alsamixer` and press `F6`? Pressing `F6` in alsamixer should allow you to select the cards recognized by the system.

Comment: i did that but it still isn't playing. the cards that are showing in alsamixer are as follows: default:0 HD-Audio Generic, default:1 HD-Audio Generic, default:2 acp

Comment: there aren't any available settings for acp when i select it

Comment: can you show the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "Audio"`?

Comment: Also, could you make sure that you have installed the following packages: `alsa-firmware`, `alsa-utils`, and `alsa-plugins`? Another command you could try is `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`. If this command outputs that playing the .wav file was successful, it could mean that the problem may not be related to ALSA.

Comment: i added the output for you

Comment: all of those are installed @Qba and the aplay command gave me a Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono

Comment: That's strange because it means that ALSA is "working", as in its not running into problems when trying to output audio. Maybe ensure that your user is in the audio group by doing `sudo usermod -a -G audio <your username>`. Also, if you aren't already, I'd highly recommend using PulseAudio alongside ALSA as it makes things a lot easier to troubleshoot and set up. You can get it by installing the packages `pulseaudio` and `pulseaudio-alsa`. You can also install a volume mixer for it,of which `pavucontrol` is a popular one.

Comment: pulseaudio tells me that there is a package confliction and so it refuses to download when i try, but i tried sudo usermod -a -G audio myusername and it didn't seem to change anything @Qba

Comment: what exactly is the package conflict?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that ALSA is defaulting to using the HDMI output for sound.  You can test this by plugging the laptop into a TV with HDMI.

You can also try to force aplay to output via your other sound device as a test: `aplay -Dhw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`.  If that works, you can use the instructions here to make card 1 default: https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Setting_the_default_device.

Comment: when i ran that i got: Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1396: Channels count non available

Comment: but still no sound